# Using animation.ArtistAnimation() in matplotlib returns a blank

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to combine a few of pictures made by matplotlib itself and some external pictures together, then export a video, but something goes wrong with my code. All the pictures combine well, but the video is totally a blank.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import image as mpimg 
from matplotlib import animation
import copy

plotfile = r'C:\Users\handa\Desktop\result.txt'
RD = np.loadtxt(plotfile)[:, 0]
PE = np.loadtxt(plotfile)[:, 1] - np.loadtxt(plotfile)[0, 1]
ims = []
for _ in range(0, 3):
    mark = [_]
    RD1 = RD[mark]
    RD2 = np.delete(RD, mark)
    PE1 = PE[mark]
    PE2 = np.delete(PE, mark)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 12))

    # plot the main part
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    line = ax1.plot(RD, PE, 'b-', label = r'NEB Energy Curve', linewidth = 3)
    scatter1 = ax1.plot(RD1, PE1, 'bo', label = r'NEB Energy Curve', markersize = 10, markerfacecolor = 'red')
    scatter2 = ax1.plot(RD2, PE2, 'bo', label = r'NEB Energy Curve', markersize = 10, markerfacecolor = 'white')
    ax1.set_xlabel('Reaction Coordinate', fontsize = 16)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Energy (eV)', fontsize = 16)
    ax1.minorticks_on()
    ax1.tick_params(which = 'both', axis = 'both', direction = 'in', labelsize = 14)

    # plot the inset
    axin1 = ax1.inset_axes([0.1, 0.45, 0.5, 0.5])
    linein = axin1.plot(RD, PE, 'b-', label = r'NEB Energy Curve', linewidth = 3)
    scatterin1 = axin1.plot(RD1, PE1, 'bo', label = r'NEB Energy Curve', markersize = 10, markerfacecolor = 'red')
    scatterin2 = axin1.plot(RD2, PE2, 'bo', label = r'NEB Energy Curve', markersize = 10, markerfacecolor = 'white')
    axin1.set_xlabel('Reaction Coordinate', fontsize = 12)
    axin1.set_ylabel('Energy (eV)', fontsize = 12)
    axin1.tick_params(which = 'both', axis = 'both', direction = 'in', labelsize = 10)
    axin1.set_xlim(0, 0.3, 0.1)
    axin1.set_ylim(-0.1, 1)

    # plot the atom figure
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
    num = str(_).zfill(4)
    atoms = mpimg.imread(f'C:\\Users\\handa\\Desktop\\atomfig\\atomfig{num}.png')
    ax2.axis(False)
    im = ax2.imshow(atoms, animated = True)
    ims.append([im])

# export the animation
fig_ani = plt.figure(figsize = (8, 12))
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig_ani, ims, interval = 500, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't see where you write it in video file. Maybe you shoud write it before `show()`

Answer (score 0):

The blank output may be caused by the automatic deletion of the initial picture matrix ( `RD2 = np.delete(RD, mark)` and `PE2 = np.delete(PE, mark)` on lines 14 and 16).